# Creating a specific macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to create a macro using Excel 2007 for some data I've collected. What I need the macro do to is, search a column and find a certain number of consecutive zero's (60) and if there is 60 consecutive zero's delete them. Any advice or help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean consecutive zeros as in a cell with 60 zeros?. Do you mean 60 consecutive cells with a value of 0? When you say delete, do you mean delete the cells or just clear the values or remove the zeros? If you want the cells deleted, should the surrounding cells go up or left?

Comment: @Justin: You might want to change `consecutive zero's` to `consecutive cells containing zero's`

Comment: @Justin. I have amended the code. See if that is what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

**LOGIC**:

1. Filter the range on the criteria
2. Store the address on the visible cells in a variable
3. Remove "$" which Excel automatically puts in the address
4. Check if the visible cell address is like "2:2" or "2:2,5:64"
5. Find the difference between the start row and end row
6. If difference is >= say 60 then clear contents.

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, times As Long, Col As Long, i As Long
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim addr As String, MyArray() As String, tmpAr() As String, num As String

    '~~> Change these as applicable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  '<~~ Sheet1
    Col = 1                                 '<~~ Col A
    num = "0"                               '<~~ Number to replace
    times = 60                              '<~~ Consecutive Cells with Numbers

    '~~> Don't change anything below this
    With ws
        lRow = .Range(ReturnName(Col) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rRange = .Range(ReturnName(Col) & "1:" & ReturnName(Col) & lRow)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers)
        With rRange
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & num
          '~~> get the visible cells address
          addr = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Address
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        addr = Replace(addr, "$", "")

        '~~> Check if addr has multiple ranges
        If InStr(1, addr, ",") Then
            MyArray = Split(addr, ",")

            '~~> get individual ranges
            For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
                tmpAr = Split(MyArray(i), ":")

                '~~> If difference is >= times then clear contents
                If Val(Trim(tmpAr(1))) - Val(Trim(tmpAr(0))) >= times - 1 Then
                    .Range(ReturnName(Col) & Trim(tmpAr(0)) & ":" & _
                    ReturnName(Col) & Trim(tmpAr(1))).ClearContents
                End If
            Next i
        Else
            tmpAr = Split(addr, ":")

            If Val(Trim(tmpAr(1))) - Val(Trim(tmpAr(0))) >= times - 1 Then
                .Range(ReturnName(Col) & Trim(tmpAr(0)) & ":" & _
                ReturnName(Col) & Trim(tmpAr(1))).ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub

'~~~> Function to retrieve Col Names from Col Numbers
Function ReturnName(ByVal numb As Long) As String
    ReturnName = Split(Cells(, numb).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Comment: +1 because I like your edit, even though you might not be answering the question... because it is kind of vague.

Comment: Thank You Daniel. However why do you think it is vague? I find it quite straight forward. (unless I have misunderstood?)

Comment: I added my questions as a comment to the question. :-) I didn't feel like asking when I first viewed it, but decided to since I saw some answers.

Comment: I read your comment and I still feel my understanding is correct (But I could be wrong LOL) And if I am wrong, I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I am in way over my head; I'm definitely a novice here. I've only created very basic macros (although my problem may be very basic for you guys!). Basically what we've done was had collected 7 days worth of data @ 1 min epochs on 120 participants. So, every min the device the participants were wearing spits out a count. Now, what we’re trying to do is get rid of what we have defined as non-wear time, which would be 60 mins of 0 counts.

Comment: So to answer Daniel’s questions what I meant was if there are 60 consecutive cells with a value of zero clear the cell and remove the zeros. I apologize for not being clear enough. Because I’m so in over my head here I’m hoping I can take what you guys come up with and adapt it to fit my form. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @DanielCook: You were right. I misunderstood. I deleted my answer but undeleted it again as I have amended the code.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have a feeling you are going to change the requirements after you run this...

Select all the cells you want to look at, then run this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteConsecutiveZeros()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim countZeros As Long
    Dim lastCellRow As Long
    Dim iCurrentRow As Long

    Set rng = Selection
    lastCellRow = rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For iCurrentRow = lastCellRow To 1 Step -1
        If (countZeros >= 60) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(rng.Cells(iCurrentRow + 59, 1).Address, rng.Cells(iCurrentRow, 1).Address).EntireRow.Delete
            countZeros = 0
        End If

        If (rng.Cells(iCurrentRow, 1).Value = 0 And rng.Cells(iCurrentRow, 1).Text <> vbNullString) Then
            countZeros = countZeros + 1
        Else
            countZeros = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```